# Android os build giving issue on MAC OS X (lion)

Tags: android, macos, build

When Running **make -j4** it stuck at this or if i remove **prebuilt** directory from root directory `java.mk` start giving issue on **JAVA_SDK_VERSION** need help

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_toro
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=IMM76I
============================================
build/core/base_rules.mk:166: *** prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver: MODULE.TARGET.EXECUTABLES.gdbserver already defined by device/samsung/tuna/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver.  Stop.
```